# Load tensorflow.js model from files with parcel

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js, parcel

I want to serve tensorflow.js models in a web app built with parcel, similar to https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/image.

I have a run.js file and a run.html as well as a folder (model1) with model.json, metadata.json and weights.bin. I am bundling all this with parcel.
The Problem is, when I import the model.json, metadata.json and weights.bin files, they are parsed, which I can't use.

I would want them in a "file" format.
I can achieve this by loading the files in the html's  element, but I would like to hand the models to the user.

**run.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div>Teachable Machine Image Model Local</div>
    <button type="button" id="loadmodel">Load Model 1</button>
    <button type="button" id="run">Start</button>

    <input type="file" id="lm1">Model</input>
    <input type="file" id="lmd1">Metadata</input>
    <input type="file" id="lw1">Weights</input>

    <script src="./run.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**run.js:**

```
import localmodel1 from "./model1/model.json";
import localmeta1 from "./model1/metadata.json";
import localweights1 from "./model1/weights.bin";
const textFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/model1/weights.bin", "utf8");
console.log(textFile);

localModel = localmodel1;
localMetadata = localmeta1;
localWeights = localweights1;
/*
fs.readFile('./model1/weights.bin', function (err, bin) {
    localweights1 = bin;
    if (err) throw err;    
});
*/
uploadModel = document.getElementById('lm1').files[0];
uploadMetadata = document.getElementById('lmd1').files[0];
uploadWeights = document.getElementById('lw1').files[0];

model = await tmImage.loadFromFiles(uploadModel, uploadWeights, uploadMetadata);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to hand the models to the user" ?

Comment: I would like the user to be able to use pretrained models that I deploy together with the code. So the user would have the option of:
a: load a pretrained model (<-- this is the problem)
b: load my own model by using the file input

Answer (score 1):

`loadFromFiles` expect arguments of type file. So there is not much you can do to load files by parcel directly apart from getting those files when the user select them.

Instead `tf.loadLayersModel` loads model from file.

The model files, needs to be put in the folder served by parcel. They don't have to be imported as if they were module.

```
const customModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(jsonUrl); // there is no need to specify weight file
```

The metadata on the other hand can be imported as a typescript file

```
import metadataJSON from "./model1/metadata.json";
const model = new CustomMobileNet(customModel, metadataJSON); // CustomMobileNet needs to be imported
```